# Install npm package without dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am looking for best solution how to install npm package without it's dependencies described in it's package.json file.

The goal is to change dependencies versions before install package. I can do it manually for one package by downloading source, but if you have many nested dependencies it becomes a problem.

Comment: This is a unique problem for which I doubt there's a way or a tool out there to do it. You'll have to code it yourself, most likely. [Post-install scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) may aid you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM install single package without rest of dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732031/npm-install-single-package-without-rest-of-dependencies)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a shell script that seems to get you the extracted files you need.

```
#!/bin/bash
package="$1"
version=$(npm show ${package} version)
archive="${package}-${version}.tgz"
curl --silent --remote-name \
  "https://registry.npmjs.org/${package}/-/${archive}"
mkdir "${package}"
tar xzf "${archive}" --strip-components 1 -C "${package}"
rm "${archive}"
```

Save it as `npm_download.sh` and run it with the name of the package you want:

`./npm_download.sh pathval`

Comment: if you have your own npm registry; replace `https://registry.npmjs.org` with a variable, e.g. `${regurl}`, and pass it as an argument, e.g. `regurl="$2"`

Answer (score 2):

Please check simialr quesition on stackexchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168034/is-there-an-option-to-install-an-npm-package-without-dependencies

My solution was to rename package.json to package.bak before the install, then reverting rename afterwards:

```
RENAME package.json package.bak
npm install <package_name> --no-save
RENAME package.bak package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I supplemented the above script to allow the specification of multiple packages, avoid the temporary downloaded file and to install the packages straight to `node_modules`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# filename suggestion: `npm-i-no-deps`

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
  package="$1"
  version=$(npm show ${package} version)
  mkdir -p "node_modules/${package}"
  echo "Installing ${package}-${version}"
  curl --silent "https://registry.npmjs.org/${package}/-/${package}-${version}.tgz" | tar xz --strip-components 1 -C "node_modules/${package}"
  shift
done
```

I found this script useful for situations where dependencies are too strict with their dependency requirements, you can install deps you know work ok without adding them to your `package.json` until the upstream dependency is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the script from mxcl to handle scoped packages (@user/package)

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# filename suggestion: `npm-i-no-deps`

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
  package="$1"
  version=$(npm show ${package} version)
  mkdir -p "node_modules/${package}"
  echo "Installing ${package}-${version}"
  packagename=$(echo $package | sed 's/@.*\///g')
  curl --silent "https://registry.npmjs.org/${package}/-/${packagename}-${version}.tgz" | tar xz --strip-components 1 -C "node_modules/${package}" 
  shift
done
```

Warning: mac has a weird version of sed, it should work but I can't guarantee.