# npm install <package> installs package, PLUS entire package.json

Tags: npm-install

When I run `npm install <package>@<version>` I am trying to only install one specific package, however, the entire `package.json` dependencies are installed along with the `<package>`. Is there any way to prevent all of the other dependency installs and only focus on the specific package?

Based off of the first few responses, it seems like `--no-optional` seems like the answer, but this is not working for me. On the first ever install with `--no-optional`, it only install the one package. But then if I run an

```
npm i
rm -rf node_modules
npm i --no-optional <package>@<version>
```

it will start installing the entire dependency list again. Try to reproduce with this `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "is-sorted": "^1.0.5",
    "moment": "2.24.0"
  }
}
```

The `--no-optional` flag will not work on consecutive runs. Running a `npm cache clean --force` does not help either

Comment: Are you referring to only the optional dependencies? Use `--no-optional` flag. The non-optional dependencies, there is no point in installing a package without its required dependencies. I suppose if you really needed to you could run the install and then remove them from your package and package.json files manually. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I have updated my question to include why `--no-optional` is not working for me

Comment: `npm i` will install missing dependencies. Don't run `npm i` without the `--no-optional` flag

Answer (score 0):

`--no-optional` argument will prevent optional dependencies from being installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the installation of optional dependencies, use `--no-optional`.

If you, for a specific reason, want to install it without *any* dependencies, this is currently not possible. It has been requested multiple times, see here:

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/340
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6712

**[Edit]** You might also want to check out these threads:

- [Is there an option to install an npm package without dependencies?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168034)
- [Install npm package without dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382773)